# Authentication in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am going to write an Authentication module using the Zend Framework 2. To help me with this process, I found this [tutorial in the web](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2012/02/18/zend-framework-2-authentication-acl-using-eventmanager/). However, when I run this module, it shows this message:

```
Class Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain does not exist
```

What is the meaning of this message?

Additionally, do you know of a Zend Framework 2 Authentication tutorial I could use for assisstance as I write my own?

Answer (score 2):

Look at ZFC-Common's [ZfcAcl](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAcl).

Comment: hi and thank you for Answer. but zfcacl is very hard and large for me. i am a beginner in zend framework .

Answer (score 1):

The EdpUser as mentioned above has been consumed by [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser). That works will with ZF2 as Evan Dot Pro is a core contributor to ZF2. In relation to managing Acl's, ZfcAcl is currently not working with ZF2 RC1. It's a little behind the time now.

They have a RFC open to make updates but that looks like it's a little way down the line. I'd possibly recommend using [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize). Zf-Commons are considering taking this over as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own customized plugin in zf2 something like this
[Acl implimentation in ZF2](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/zend-framework-2-controllerpluginmanager-append-controller-pluginto-all-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Authentication + Acl using EventManager](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2012/02/18/zend-framework-2-authentication-acl-using-eventmanager/). It looks like easier than ZfcAcl.

Answer (score 0):

I was also using this tutorial month ago is to old and not working with beta5
You can try to play with 
https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpUser it nicely writen and have cool things as view helpers for login form and auth status

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own authentication adapter for this in one of my projects. I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/renaatdemuynck/5fccfb6b4900e8347fa3). You can use it like this:

```
$adapter = new AdapterChain([
    new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap(/* ... */),
    new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable(/* ... */)
    // ...
]);

$authService = new AuthenticationService();
$authService->setAdapter($adapter);
```